# Does the existence of all the Fourier transforms imply $f \in L^1$?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

It is trivial that for $f \in L^1$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-2\pi i xy} dx$$
converges. I was just wondering whether the converse is true:
Given a (let's say continuous) function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-2\pi i xy} dx$$ 
is convergent for all $y$, does it imply $f \in L^1$?
I'm really not so sure what I should believe here since I neither see a counterexample nor a way to prove this.
This question must have been considered before, but I couldn't find any references online.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, the integrals can of course not be absolutely convergent, otherwise the result would be trivial. By saying that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \dots$ exists I really mean that $\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_0^T \dots$ and $\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{-T}^0 \dots$ both exist.

Comment: I don't think tat the integral is even defined (in the Lebesgue sense)  if $f \not\in L^1$, since $|f(x)e^{-2\pi i xy}| = |f(x)|$.

Comment: Okay I should have been more precise. Of course if the problem is to be interesting at all, these integrals cannot be absolutely convergent i.e. we really need to read them as $\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_0^T+\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{-T}^0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier transform can exist even if we have conditional convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$.

If $f \in L^1$ then by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, the Fourier transform
$$\hat{f}(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e ^{iyx} \, dy$$

must decay to $0$ as $|y| \to \infty$.  Any function with a convergent Fourier transform without this property is not in $L^1$.

An example is

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\sin(x^2) & x \geqslant 0 \\ 0  & x < 0 \end{cases}$$

where the Fourier (cosine) transform is

$$\hat{f}(y) = \int_0^\infty \sin (x^2)\, \cos(yx) \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}\left[\cos \frac{y^2}{4} - \sin \frac{y^2}{4}\right]$$

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer! A natural followup question would be: Is it necessarily true that $\widehat{f}(y)$ is bounded? (This would trivially be true if $f \in L^1$ but remains true in your example.)

Comment: @Tintarn: You're welcome.  Good question -- maybe worth posting -- and I will think about it.